# How to send new order emails through SMTP Pro using Observer

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, smtp, send-mail

I'm running Magento 1.9.2.4 and it's not sending new order emails if I choose a certain payment method.

I know the error is in the payment method because cron jobs are running and every other payment method sends their new order email. I'm using SMTP Pro (aschroder).

This faulty payment method let's me choose the order state after the payment is accepted.

I'd like to use an Observer to send new order emails, and triggers when a certain state is chosen for an order.

There are several guides out there explaining how to set an observer, but I'd like to know how can I call SMTP Pro to send the email.

Answer (score 1):

go to app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
line
 line 407 put

```
if (!($this->hasQueue()) && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)
```